# Programming a Colour Blend

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Huge thanks to those who have helped me find my footing especially to @bRost03 who did the programming below.

I hope you guys don't mind if I clarify one thing about the programming - I think I have sorted most of it out and it is a very short query!

Below is the code from my Mathematica terminal:

```
data = {{{20., 25., 55.,}, {35., 25., 40.,}, {10., 15., 75.,}, {5., 50., 45.,}, {25., 65., 10.,}, {55., 25., 20.,}}}
toGrid[p_] := 1/2 {2 p[[2]] + p[[3]], Sqrt[3] p[[3]]};
dataPts = {10 toGrid[Most@#], Last@#} & /@ data;
pts3D = Select[Tuples[Range[0, 10], {3}], #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] == 10 &];
pts = toGrid /@ pts3D;
ptsG = Table[toGrid /@ Select[pts3D, #[[i]] == 0 &], {i, 3}];
lines = {Thread[{ptsG[[1]], ptsG[[2]]}], 
   Thread[{ptsG[[2]], ptsG[[3]]}], 
   Thread[{ptsG[[1]], Reverse[ptsG[[3]]]}]};
st[sz_] := Style[#, Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", sz] &;
rot = 60 Degree;
ticks = st[12] /@ Table[10 i, {i, 0, 10}];
labels = {Rotate[Text[st[16]["Carbs"], {1.5, 5}], rot],
   Text[st[16]["Fats"], {5, -1}],
   Rotate[Text[st[16]["Protein"], {8.5, 5}], -rot]};
mkTicks[ind_, ang_, off_] := Table[
Rotate[Text[If[ind == 2, Reverse[ticks], ticks][[i]], 
    ptsG[[ind, i]] + off], ang], {i, Length[ticks]}]
```

As you can see, my sample data is shown, with the set of three numbers being my percentage of each nutrient (in the order Protein, Fat, Carbohydrate)
**1)How do I let Mathematica know which number is which?**

The only other thing was about the colour...
If you look at the second picture - **how can I tell Mathematica to assign a colour to different sleeping hours** (a fourth value not included in the picture) with the following divisions:

7.9 = red, 8.15 being blue and 8.7 being red, with the in-between values a proportional blend of these three?

I think I want something like this:

```
Graphics[{Point /@ pts, labels, Line /@ lines, mkTicks[1, rot, {1/4, 1/4}],
 mkTicks[2, 0, {-2/5, 0}], mkTicks[3, -rot, {1/5,-1/3}], Opacity[0.25],
 {FaceForm@Blend[{Red, Blue,Green}, #[[-1]]], Disk[#[[1]], 0.2]} & /@ dataPts}]
```

But the code above is for the following divisions:
red is for 0,  blue is for 1/2 and green is for 1

Many many thanks for ALL help! I am eternally grateful

Comment: Editing - many thanks @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: can you add the missing fourth column values in `data`?

Answer (score 2):

Your concept works nice:

```
Graphics[{Point /@ pts, labels, Line /@ lines, 
  mkTicks[1, rot, {1/4, 1/4}], mkTicks[2, 0, {-2/5, 0}], 
  mkTicks[3, -rot, {1/5, -1/3}], Opacity[0.25]}]
```

[image: 2d graphics mix plot]

The rest is a big misconeption.

a) This is 2D-Graphics.
b) Disk is a 2D-Graphics-built-in: Disk[{x,y},r]
c) x and y are the only coordinates in contrast to the three coordinates in dataPts.
d) FaceForm is not needed to color a Disk.
e) Blend suffices for coloring.
f) The set of data in dataPts appear inconsistent for purposes.
g) The is no clue which of the coordinate are targeted for coloring.

A functioning example without map:

```
Graphics[{Point /@ pts, labels, Line /@ lines, 
  mkTicks[1, rot, {1/4, 1/4}], mkTicks[2, 0, {-2/5, 0}], 
  mkTicks[3, -rot, {1/5, -1/3}], 
  Opacity[0.25], {Blend[{{7.9, Blue}, {8.15, Yellow}, {8.7, Red}}, 7],
    Disk[{2, 1.7}, 0.3], 
   Blend[{{3.9, Blue}, {7.15, Yellow}, {8.7, Red}}, 8], 
   Disk[{6, 5.2}, 0.3], 
   Blend[{{7.9, Blue}, {8.15, Yellow}, {4.7, Red}}, 7], 
   Disk[{4, 3.5}, 0.3]}}]
```

[image: 2d graphics mix plot]

a) The 3D coordinates have to be mapped appropriately into the mixing triangle.
b) The coloring has to set accordingly.

Have a look at stackexchange.com with the search feature and select your best fit for the mixing graphics from the existing examples in the question.

Have a look at:

[how-to-plot-ternary-density-plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39733/how-to-plot-ternary-density-plots)
[how-can-i-draw-ternary-plot-by-these-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119328/how-can-i-draw-ternary-plot-by-these-data)
[how-to-conveniently-plot-3-category-dirichlet-data-in-equilateral-triangle-inste](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172412/how-to-conveniently-plot-3-category-dirichlet-data-in-equilateral-triangle-inste/172421#172421)

[constructing-a-ternary-histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192938/constructing-a-ternary-histogram)

[how-to-plot-curves-in-ternary-plot-triangular-plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66168/how-to-plot-curves-in-ternary-plot-triangular-plot)

```
 tercp[cp_Graphics] :=
    Quiet@Cases[ Normal@First@Cases[cp, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity] ,
        Line[x_] :> Line[{
           1 - #[[1]] + #[[2]],
           Sqrt[3] (1 - #[[1]] - #[[2]])}/2 & /@
             Select[x, Total[#] <= 1 &] ], Infinity] 

 Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}}],
         {Dashed,
Table[ tercp [ ContourPlot[(1 - b - a) == ci , {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] ],{ci, .1, .9, .1}],
Table[tercp [ ContourPlot[a == ci , {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] ], {ci, .1, .9, .1}],
Table[ tercp [ ContourPlot[b == ci , {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] ] , {ci, .1, .9, .1}]},
Table[ {Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   tercp [ ContourPlot[Abs[b - a] == (sig - 2 (1 - b - a) + 1)^.35,
       {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] ] }, {sig, -1, 1, .2}]}]
```

[image: 2d graphics plot ternary mixing]

Answer (score 0):

Use the form `Blend[{{x1, color1}, {x2, color2}, {x3, color3},...}, x]` to get `colori` when `x == xi`:

```
blend = Blend[{{7.9, Red}, {8.15, Yellow}, {8.7, Red}}, #] &;

GraphicsGrid[Partition[
 Table[Graphics[{blend[x], Rectangle[], Black, Text[Style[x, 14], {1, 1}/2]}],
       {x, 7.55, 9, .05}],
   10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but I did want it in a ternary plot - I have done that above - could I combine the two?